# make a mulitingual wordpress website Arabic-english

Tags: multi-language

I want to make a website in both languages Arabic and English, in the way that I can change from Arabic to English from the upper menu. I want to make it as word-press based website and buy a theme to use it and base my website upon it. note that arabic is written from Right to left, so we have to take this into consideration as well.
is there a possibility for that and how it can be done. if there any plugin I can do?

Comment: yes it is possible and there are plugins for that, although you don't really need them, but the question itself doesn't fit the site as it is too broad and asks for recommendation. This topic was discussed a lot here, please do some searching and when you will have a more specific question there will be better chance of you getting a useful answer to it.

Comment: Include two things into your search: ["WordPress Multisite"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=wordpress+multisite) and ["WordPress Translation"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=wordpress+translation). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. definitely will put them your input into my consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If your site has the same content in both languages, you may try the plugin I have written called [Transposh](http://transposh.org), which allows you to handle this with ease.

Support for RTL languages is embedded, where the theme has support for this. On the default themes it works quite well.

If you have different content for different languages, there are other plugins to try, and the multisite route is also quite notable.

Good luck,

Comment: Yes it does have the same content but I want the possibility of adding content to gallery/blog, also I want to ask you about your plugin does it do like google translation type of translation or I get to choose the content I want?